# c# NullReferenceException in linq query

Tags: c#

In my code:

```
decimal maxPrice = list.Max(i => i.price);
```

Getting error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
NullReferenceException was unhandled by code.

The i value becomes null, though the list count is 6709. How do I resolve this?

Comment: `list.Max(i => (null != i) ? i.price : decimal.MinValue)`

Comment: I tried but now it give me another error - Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.

Comment: hm, are you using some threads/async's? This  error occurs only when list modified from another thread.

Comment: yes, you are right

Answer (score 2):

So your list contains nulls.

Either filter them: `list.Where(l => l != null).Max(...)`, or prevent the nulls to end up in the list in the first place.

Comment: Why not close this as duplicate?

Comment: Because I'm tired of setting a good example when other 100K+ rep users don't seem to care either and post answers to questions they _have_ to know to be duplicate.

Comment: I know its extremely annoying, but sometimes there are *so many duplicates!*.